# iOS : bubble text?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitextfield, uitextview

Any idea what's the code for getting text with every letter in bubble like here :
Take a look :
http://apps.su/program/24939/bubble-your-text.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it seems to be doing is converting the letters into these unicode characters: http://www.bubbleballtext.com/unicode

**Update**

Here you go, it's called 'Enclosed Aphanumerics' - http://unicode.org/charts/nameslist/c_2460.html

Comment: The code depends on what approach you take but really all you need to do is map a-z, A-Z and 0-9 to the corresponding unicode representation and use those characters instead. So if you see an 'a', replace it with U+24D0, if you see an 'A', use U+24B6 instead. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/QUrG8/1/) that does it in HTML. Note that that code is very rough, probably not the most efficient and uses HTML entities.